# How to create sudo account while operating Ubuntu in DVD trial mode

Tags: boot, system-installation, sudo, dvd

Today I discovered that I could not save word processing files to my hard drive and files could only be opened in read-only mode. Then I discovered it was a systemwide problem affecting even an attempt to navigate in Firefox. I attempted to reboot the system, Ubuntu Studio 20.10, and ended up with scores of lines of an error message or system fault.

My Web search suggests I might be experiencing a dead or dying HDD. I burned an ISO to a DVD to attempt to use it to boot up and check the problem drive. The actions need root or sudo privileges.

How do I create a user with sudo privileges when booted from  a Ubuntu Studio DVD? Should I use regular Ubuntu instead? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with sudoers. You should be able to run commands using sudo in a live session and you don't need a password.  It sounds like you are trying to save files to a volume that is mounted read only. Sudoers can't do anything about that except to unmount the drive and mount it with rw access.  Check the "Disks" application for a GUI option to mount volumes

Comment: If your root file system keeps changing to read only, unfortunately that is often a sign of a dying hard drive. You'll need to choose advanced options in GRUB and run `fsck` on your file system from a root shell prompt with networking. This should fix file system errors and allow you to mount the file system RW.  But if the hard drive is indeed dying, it could go read only again. Back up while you still can

Comment: @Nmath, thanks for your comments. I had been following a recommended solution I found from a search and it included running commands as a sudo user and restarting the system When I tried from the DVD and attempted the action without sudo-ing, the action failed, hence my question about creating a user that would last through a system reboot, since I imagine, information would not be saved to the DVD but in memory. Anyway, I bought a new drive, installed it and stuck the faulty one in an external case and was able to copy the data files. It does have some bad sectors appparently.